# Need Convert Binary file to Txt file

Tags: c++

Actually I have huge point data set in text format for example (min 49000 KB my file size), in same style 6 numerical values per 1 line and in 2nd line again have 6 numbers
first lie: 1 234 3412 4567 12 5678
second line: 2 452 1234 1233 34 3421
third line :3 123 4532 4530 45 5643
………………………..

Firstly, I wish to convert this file into binary file (dat format), after that I want to convert this again for text file (txt). I have written some codes for the conversion ascii to dat, but after run my program I got my binary (dat) file output like:
*l*_š™_>¥ÝƒJÂ*C_l__
×#?¦ÝƒJÂ*C_l__Âõ=¦ÝƒJ_À*C_l_*š™*?§ÝƒJq½*C_l__
×£=§ÝƒJ_®*C_l__)_?§ÝƒJö¨*C_l__Âõ<¨ÝƒJH¡*C_l_**® ?¨ÝƒJ¸ž*C_l**
×#<©ÝƒJ)œ*C_l_*_*_?©ÝƒJ{”*C
may be this is not a correct output of dat file, however I want to convert this dat file agagin into ascii (txt) file. If any one can help to write c++ codes for this thanks

Comment: Is this binary file in a format you know? Do you want to convert the bytes written to it into a readable format? Would [Base64 Encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) be suitable for you?

Comment: yes format of this binary file is .dat, i want to convert it text file like my original one: numerical values in line by line

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make heads and tails of your binary format, you should use an hex viewer. There are thousands of them out there, just pick one.

Say that you read four numbers from your text file:

```
int code()
{
    int a, b, c, d;
    ifstream fin( "data.txt" );
    ofstream fout( "data.dat", ios::binary );

    fin >> a >> b >> c >> d;

    fout.write( &a, sizeof( int ) );
    fout.write( &b, sizeof( int ) );
    fout.write( &c, sizeof( int ) );
    fout.write( &d, sizeof( int ) );
}

int main()
{
    code();
}
```

Now, you will have a data.dat file that you basically does not make sense in a text editor. But you can use am hexadecimal viewer and find sixteen bytes (4 bytes * 4 bytes for *ints*, in a 32bit machine), with the values for these four variables.

Another way to check that your program is working correctly, is coding the decoder that will convert the data file again to text. Then you can compare the original one and the new one, and see whether there are differences or not.

```
int decode()
{
    int a, b, c, d;
    ifstream fin( "data.dat", ios::binary );
    ofstream fout( "data2.txt" );

    fin.read( &a, sizeof( int ) );
    fin.read( &b, sizeof( int ) );
    fin.read( &c, sizeof( int ) );
    fin.read( &d, sizeof( int ) );

    fout << a << ' ' << b << ' ' << c << ' ' << d;

}
```

If you now add a call to *decode()* in your **main** function, you will end up with two files, data.txt (the original) and data2.txt (the target one). You can now compare them, even visually, and see whether the data inside is the same one.

Comment: i didn'i got it give me example pls.

Comment: I've extended my answer in order to respond you more correctly. Hope this helps.

Comment: if you extend it to 6 numbers and put while loops in to hand the multiple lines/sets of 6 values, you'll have basically written a complete solution.  Worth pointing out that - if the number are known to fall in a lesser range such as that spanned by 16-bit values, `int16_t` (from cstdint, or __int32 if you're on Windoze) a smaller binary file would result.

Comment: @Tony, yes, but I think that @aki will prefer to understand it instead of offering a complete solution to just copy & paste. Interesting point about filesize; however, depending on the combination of compiler and OS, it is possible for the optimization to fail back to the original size.